# Why re.search(r'(ab*)','aaAaABBbbb',re.I) in python gives result 'a' instead of 'ABBbbb' though 're.I' is used?

Tags: python, regex

In python, `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

So why don't we get output as **'ABBbbb'** in **Ex(1)** as we found in **Ex(2)** and **Ex(3)** below.

Ex(1)

```
>>> s=re.search(r'(ab*)','aaAaABBbbb',re.I)
>>> print s.group()
a
```

Ex(2)

```
>>> s=re.search(r'(ab.*)','aaAaABBbbb',re.I)
>>> print s.group()
ABBbbb
```

Ex(3)

```
>>> s=re.search(r'(ab+)','aaAaABBbbb',re.I)
>>> print s.group()
ABBbbb
```

Comment: because `re.search` would return only the first match. Try `re.findall`

Comment: you should try `re.search('(a*b*), 'aaAaABBbbb', re.I)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj is right; `re.findall(r'(ab*)','aaAaABBbbb',re.I)` would return `['a', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'ABBbbb']`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example 1 is searching for `a` followed by zero or more `b`, ignoring case. This matches right at the beginning of the string. The regex engine will see that match and use it. It won't look for any other matches.

Example 2 is searching for `ab` followed by as much of the string as it can eat. Example 3 is searching for `a` following by at least one `b`. The difference is that each of these needs at least one `b`, while Example 1 does not.

Comment: An upvote in less than 18 seconds? That's fast reading on someone's part :)

Comment: 18 seconds is much for this answer. Took me 10 seconds to upvote.

Comment: I appreciate the way you cleared my doubt. :) Thanks @Tom Zych

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, I suppose. It's often easier all around to just explain it, rather than hunt around for the duplicate. Granted, the system will fill up with a lot of duplicates that way.

Answer (score 2):

[`search`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> checks for a match *anywhere* in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

---

```
re.search(r'(ab*)', 'aaAaABBbbb', re.I)
```

This will try to match `a` (case ignored) followed by *zero or more* `b`. It find that match in the first `a`, since it's followed by zero `b`, and it returned it.

```
re.search(r'(ab.*)', 'aaAaABBbbb', re.I)
```

This one will try to match `a`, followed by `b` and then with anything (`.*` is *greedy*). It matches `ABBbbb` because it's the first sequence that matches the regex.

```
re.search(r'(ab+)', 'aaAaABBbbb', re.I)
```

Finally, this will match `a`, followed by *at least* one `b` (again, case ignored). That first match is `ABBbbb`, and it's returned.